# react useEffect : Outer scope values like 'authService._user' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to use useEffect to check if user signed in print username on menu.
but I get this warning:

> React Hook useEffect has an unnecessary dependency:
>   'authService._user'. Either exclude it or remove the dependency array.
>   **Outer scope values like 'authService._user' aren't valid dependencies**
>   because mutating them doesn't re-render the component 
>   react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

this is my useEffect in **navbar**:

```
    useEffect(() => {
    setUsername(authService._user.username);
}, [authService._user])
```

and this is my authorise service example:

```
interface User {
username: string;
password: string;
}
export class AuthorizeService {
_user: User = {
    username: '',
    password: ''
};
_isAuthenticated = false;

isAuthenticated() {
    return this._isAuthenticated;
}

Authenticate(username: string, password: string) {
    this._isAuthenticated = true; //I will add fetch latter here
    this._user =  {
        username: username,
        password: password
    }
}
}

const authService = new AuthorizeService();

export default authService;
```

btw everything work great but there is warning in console.

my question is: **is that the right way to do it? and why there is warning.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fill that array only if it is coming from props.

Take a look at https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html in the section "Tip: Optimizing Performance by Skipping Effects"

But I suggest to read the whole docs about useEffects, there are some important details there and its a short documentation.

Comment: only if it is coming from items that are re-initialised every render*, you could have a `const foo = "bar"` variable that is created on render, used in a `useEffect`, which is why the react error uses the word `scope`. "Outer scope" means "exists outside of the component"

Comment: Thank you for your clarification, so like samples in link above is it better to subscribe a function to my authService?

Comment: Or maybe in simple way remove array dependency and check in every render of Navbar?

Answer (score 1):

**Minimal reproduction and explanation of the error**

I was a bit confused by the error in the middle of a large project, but I understood why it happens and created a minimal example. Consider this minimal Next.js example with a Hoc:

pages/index.js

```
import React from 'react'

function HomeHoc(msg) {
  return function Home() {
    React.useEffect(() => {
      document.title = msg
    }, [msg])
    return <p>{ msg }</p>
  }
}

export default HomeHoc('asdf')
```

I had mindlessly added `msg` to the `React.useEffect` previously to try and satisfy `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` in several places, and then `next lint` gave me:

> 7:8  Warning: React Hook React.useEffect has an unnecessary dependency: 'msg'. Either exclude it or remove the dependency array. Outer scope values like 'msg' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

But clearly, this `msg` dependency is not necessary, because `msg` is defined in the `HomeHoc` scope, and goes to the `Home` component as a closure. It therefore obviously cannot change once a `Home` is created.

Therefore, you should just remove `msg` from the dependency list as suggested by the lint message, as it won't ever make any difference.

The rest of the reproduction setup:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "with-eslint",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "12.0.7",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.24.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.0.7"
  }
}
```

.eslintrc

```
{
  "extends": "next",
  "root": true
}
```